# How to mention colleagues from work in my thesis

Tags: citations, thesis, acknowledgement

Right now I am writing a thesis in a Russian university on data mining to obtain bachelor degree. The thesis is related to my job field and I use an inner implementation of an algorithm to process some data. My supervisor is ok with using his code. I will cite the original paper that describes the algorithm, but how do I mention the supervisor in my thesis. Can I just say mention them during presentation as people who helped me?

Answer (score 1):

Acknowledge those who should be acknowledged by name and for what they have contributed. A supervisor should be acknowledged for being a supervisor, a person providing code for providing code and referencing a paper published on a code or whatever you use should of course be in the reference list. It sounds as if one person fits all three bills and then you should simply cite the paper and acknowledge the person in the acknowledgement for being supervisor and providing code. You also find that there are more personal reasons to thank the person as well. It is not uncommon that supervisors receive acknowledgements for other guidance during the work. But only what is deserved should be mentioned. You can certainly build in an acknowledgement to your supervisor during the talk, either in the beginning, when you mention the code  or at the end. You could also stick the reference into the presentation when you present the code. It is always customary to acknowledge the supervisor anyway and whether you do it at the beginning or end is a matter of tradition or style.